# Add image in an existing PDF with itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

SO i have a created a PDF template form with textbox which are editable fields. I am able to generate the pre-populated PDF with values from my database into the template through MVC 4.0 Application. Which works fine. Now i want to add a image from a folder into the PDF which will distinguished  one form with another form. The image will depend on the user in-put. Image will go at the bottom of the PDF. I don't see any image-box or image container as a filed option. Only one i can see are text-box,checkbox,radio,list box etc but nothing like a iimage holder.

Dose any one know how to add image dynamically into PDF?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. A PDF form should not be confused with an HTML form. They're different beasts. In a PDF form, there's no post-type request-response cycle. The entered text is just set in the PDF as if it was hard-coded in the PDF.

Comment: " I am able to generate the pre-populated PDF with values from my database into the template through MVC 4.0 Application." How are you doing this? I can bet you are using a library, and it's very likely that the same library can be used for adding images to an existing PDF file.

Comment: @yms yes i am using the itextsharp library. I am looking into now as we speak, I was looking for a form filed before but now looking into library.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question in the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically in [chapter 8](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8). In section 8.2.3, entitled "Pushbuttons", I explain that we usually use buttons as placeholders for images, because buttons can have an *icon*.

The [ReplaceIcon](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=156) example shows how you can replace the icon of an exising button. As you are using C#, you may want to take a look at [ReplaceIcon.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter08/ReplaceIcon.cs):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(aPdf);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
        AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
        PushbuttonField ad = form.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("button_name");
        ad.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
        ad.ProportionalIcon = true;
        ad.Image = Image.GetInstance(yourImage);
        form.ReplacePushbuttonField("button_name", ad.Field);
      }
    }
    // ms will contain your PDF in memory
}
reader.Close();
```

Note that the line `ad.ProportionalIcon = true;` will scale your image so that it fits the button.